# Multiple specific plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

my interrogation is the following :

I have a code that generates a plot using :

```
fig = plt.figure( figsize=(6.5,10))
ax = fig.gca()
```

[image]

I've used this routine to generate multiple plots. Is there a simple way to make the plot look like :
[image]

I know there is a command plt.subplots but I dont know how to place each plots in this configuration. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 5)`?

Answer (score 1):

`gridspec` is your friend here:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec 

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,8))

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 5)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1])
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2])
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(gs[3])
ax5 = fig.add_subplot(gs[4])

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)
ax2.set_yticks([])
ax3.set_yticks([])
ax4.set_yticks([])
ax5.set_yticks([])
```

Comment: Hi, i've tried your suggestion. I obtain a plot that looks like the one I've put in the description of the problem, however the leftside of one is not the right side of the other ( there is a gap=, do you see a way to do that ?

Comment: `plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)`?

Comment: @DavidG is right - edited my answer to add that and removed yticks since that would probably make sense for this type of plot too.